# Column-count overflowing down (XSL-FO + Antenna House Formatter)

Tags: xslt, multiple-columns, xsl-fo, antenna-house

I am working with XSL-FO in combination with the Antenna House Formatter (V6) where I have a `block-container` with `column-count: 3` on it. The problem is the overflowing content does not go to the right but instead goes below it. I can "fix" the issue by creating more columns and increasing the width of the `block-container` but I dislike like that as it's a hack more than anything.

I have illustrated what it does and what I want:
[image: Column problem - Current/Want]

Here is my document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:axf="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="id0" page-width="210mm" page-height="200mm" axf:crop-offset="0mm" axf:bleed="0mm">
      <fo:region-body/>
      <fo:region-before extent="0cm"/>
      <fo:region-after extent="0cm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="id0">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block-container background-color="cmyk(0,0.87,0.83,0.3)" height="50mm" width="210mm" column-count="3" column-gap="1mm">
        <fo:block hyphenate="true" language="da">

          <fo:block-container width="70mm">
            <fo:block font-size="15pt" line-height="20pt">
              <fo:inline linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed" font-family="DINRegular" color="cmyk(0.1,0.13,0.08,0.8)" font-size="15pt">Idet antallet af redigerbare felter per sag begrænses af afhængigheden til ejendomstype og antal ejendomstypebeskrivelser valgt, så foreslår vi, at sagsdataene vedligeholdes under én og samme fane, Data. Derfor er rækkefølgen hvormed brugeren bør vedligeholde dataene som følger. For at vedligeholde data på en sag skal man klikke på sagen og herefter på fanen Ejendomsdata. Dette åbner fanen Data, som er den første under Ejendomsdata.</fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:block-container>

          <fo:block-container width="70mm">
            <fo:block font-size="20pt" line-height="25pt">
              <fo:inline linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed" font-family="DINLight" color="cmyk(0,0,0,1)" font-size="20pt">Endvidere er der afhængigheder mellem valgte ejendomstype og de data, der kan vedligeholdes under Vilkår og Økonomi, samt mellem antallet af (og hvilke) valgte ejendomstypebeskrivelser og de data der kan vedligeholdes hertil. Endnu en årsag til, at vi foreslår, at sagsdataene vedligeholdes under én og samme fane er, at eventuelle ændringer, som foretages på én fane og gemmes, kan have konsekvenser for indholdet under andre faner.</fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:block-container>

        </fo:block>
      </fo:block-container>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: Can I make a try?, see answer window for displaying result, if display is ok, then we can see the XSL:FO text.

Comment: below result text for mat is ok?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is the above format of display Ok?